# Australian 457 partner same financial support and health insurance?

Tags: working-visas, australia, dependent-visa

What does it mean that your partner must have same levels of financial support and health insurance on the [457 Australian work visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/457-)? I should mention I am from the UK and I don't have health insurance as we have the National Health Service which is payed for from the tax you pay.

Here is the quote from the Australian Department of Immigration and Border Protection.

> They must also be able to show they have the same lev​​els of financial support and health insurance as you.

Comment: My guess: it also says that the sponsoring company must name any dependents/partners in the documents. Hopefully, they also mention health insurance. For financial support, either own funds, or statements from you that you'll provide support.

Comment: Wouldn't the Australians be interested in you having Health Insurance in Australia, to cover you when you got there, rather than back home?

Comment: @Gagravarr ok that makes sense. My partner and I need to be on the same health insurance in Australia. What about "financial support"?